# Update Resources / Hot deploy not working with tomee and IntelliJ

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, apache-tomee

I am trying out IntelliJ for the first time and I am using tomEE. I can't get my changes reflected unless i redeploy the war (remove it then redeploy it).

What I do is the following:

Run configurations - exploded war, selected Update classes and resources on "Update". Set it to do it on frame deactivation. Tried to do it manually with CTRL+F10.

No changes gets reflected, not in a helloworld.jsp / facelet.

Running:
IntelliJ 12.0.4
TomEE webprofile 1.5.1

The file in /target is changed. New files work fine as well, some kind of cache or something is causing this it feels like. Not the browsers cache because I tried with many browsers / cleared all data etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-eclipse.html) you need to have this code in `web.xml` to enable **JSP Hot Deployment**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>development</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

The relevant part is setting `development` parameter to **true**.

Comment: I had a blank web.xml basically. Added projectstage for jsf2 and a bunch of other standard configuration and it works!

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction